# TFS downgrade data tier from SQL Server Enterprise to Standard

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2012

I have installed TFS2013 with SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, unfortunately that was not what I intended so now I want to downgrade to SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition.

I have followed these steps:

1. Disabled data compression in all TFS databases
2. Stopped all collections in TFS
3. Made a backup with TFSBackup
4. Made a complete uninstall of SQL Server 2012 EE
5. Installed SQL Server SE
6. Restored using TFSRestore

However, when I enter the TFS Administration Console to start the collections again, I get the following error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable ”@StartTime”

I also tried to do attach of the old databases instead of restore, but I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. The collation of the new DB instance was incorrect, Finnish_Swedish_CS_AS, after changing it to Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS everything works ok.

Update: Collation needs to be changed for SSAS as well if reporting is used, and a new analysis database must be created.